# How to handle "Cannot find or open the PDB file" at VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, upnp

I am trying to debug a project, that has libs files, libs files and exe files, If I run this project without debugging it compiles well and execute well.

But its debugging doesn’t work, It says : [Cannot find or open the PDB file]
* tvctrlpt.exe is the name of exe on which I am working now.
Seems I am making mistakes in project build debugger settings ?

Do I need to consider anything specific on this ?

[for your information – I am doing the windows debugging for following : http://sourceforge.net/projects/pupnp/forums/forum/569833/topic/5409226]

See below log:

**tvctrlpt.exe': Loaded 'D:\libupnp\build\vc10\out.vc10.Win32\Debug\bin\tvctrlpt.exe', Cannot find or open the PDB file**

EDIT

Here I am using the http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/ [ libupnp 1.6.17] , it compile well, and run as usual, but while running the debugger - it says - Cannot find or open the PDB file.

searched all across internet, and tried all the ways for various settings, but it didn't work, seems it require little more deep knowledge to do that.

Or  some settings etc..

Comment: Do you have a .pdb file?

Comment: Yes, PDB file exist, The PDB file exists in the same directory as the dll, I have also cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: What does the message say in the output window? It will tell you what the reason for not loading it is.